# Variable might not have been initialized in Delphi function

Tags: delphi

I am building this function that will return whether an ID is returned by the query or not. I am new to Delphi, and I am getting the error

> Variable emailExistsId may not be initialized.

My code:

```
function emailExists (const APersonId: TStandardPK) : Boolean ;
var
  Email : TPhoneEmail;
  emailExistsId: TStandardPK;

begin
  Email := TPhoneEmail.Create(nil);
  try
    emailExistsId :=  Email.qrySelect.FieldByName('id').AsFloat;
  finally
    if emailExistsId <> 0  then
    Result := TRUE
    else
    Result :=False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Why would there be an exception if no email had been assigned? My reading is that if no email had been assigned, the `id` value would be zero. Although it is kinda weird that `id` is considered as a float ....

Comment: It's nice to have floating point primary keys :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan line `Email.qrySelect.FieldByName('id').AsFloat` can throw exception. If it does, then assignment to `emailExistsId` inside try block would not be completed.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Which is precisely what I stated in my answer. But why would you expect that to happen as normal behaviour?  Why would you propose swallowing such exceptions and returning `False`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because that is what OP seems to want. I am not saying that is good or bad approach, it is hard to say without more context. I have seen plenty of such code where people expected boolean result and all they got was the exception they were not prepared for.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I personally think that the finally was just rather confused. Note the leak after all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I was in the middle of extending my answer, when you posted yours with more or less same content. That is why I deleted mine. It makes no sense to have two.

Comment: @Victoria, I hope you are joking.

Comment: @kobik, of course I'm joking :) I appreciate creativity in this case.

Comment: @Victoria, Well I'm not sure OP is aware of your sarcasm :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, Even if the OP wants a Boolean result, some exceptions are not be ignored and swallowed. IMO, this is the case here.

Comment: @kobik I never said otherwise. I merely pointed out what kind of logic OP probably expects, and is not getting with his code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hint is correct. Consider the code:

```
try
  emailExistsId := Email.qrySelect.FieldByName('id').AsFloat;
finally
  if emailExistsId <> 0  then
    Result := TRUE
  else
    Result :=False;
end;
```

If evaluation of `Email.qrySelect.FieldByName('id').AsFloat` results in an exception then `emailExistsId` will not be assigned a value. Your code then reads `emailExistsId` in its uninitialised state. Hence the compiler producing a hint. Of course it's all rather moot because the exception propagates and the caller does not receive the return value in any case.

Your code is far too complex in any case, and it leaks. It should be:

```
function emailExists(const APersonId: TStandardPK): Boolean;
var
  Email: TPhoneEmail;
begin
  Email := TPhoneEmail.Create(nil);
  try
    Result := Email.qrySelect.FieldByName('id').AsFloat <> 0;
  finally
    Email.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm liking this code :) I will accept it in a few minutes

Comment: On a side note, I wonder why you used `AsFloat`. It seems odd to me that something named `id` would be a floating point value.

Comment: it's because the ID is a float. One question, the qryselect has a parameter in it, how can I call the query passing also the value?

Comment: OK, fair enough! As for the question relating to the parameter, that's a different question altogether. We don't have sufficient detail to answer that, but in any case, you should not ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would something as qrySelect.FieldByName('id').AsFloat.Value.....

Comment: You write: "it's because the ID is a float". Thats probably a wrong design. Numeric IDs should be ordinal types, e.g. Integer.